# import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream; causing issues with printing to a file

Tags: java, zip

question answered. Thank you all for your willingness to help and offer your aid.

```
Writer output = null;
    File pdfFile = new File("MANIFEST.txt");//create text file
    try {
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pdfFile));
    } catch (IOException e) {
         //TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){//create manifesto of pdfs in directory
        try {

            System.out.println(copy[i]);
            output.write(copy[i]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

copy is an array of strings. The contents properly print to the console, but not to the file (the file is created though). When I include the import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;, alot of things throw exceptions (such as output.write gives "unhandled exception type IOEception") unless I put them in a try catch.

Comment: You don't solve _syntax_ errors with try/catch. Do you mean you get any exceptions? If yes, post them here.

Comment: Not sure what is your problem. But, I assume that the contents you are printing are not seen in the file. I believe you should be flushing the buffered writer to force write to the file outside the for loop.

Comment: sorry, I knew that but used the wrong word. w/o the try catch output.write gives an exception "unhandled exception type IOException"

Comment: And what is the error message of the exception? Just post the complete message including stack trace.

Comment: it didn't give any exception at run time, but when I changed it to i<copy.length then I got the run time exception                            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException   
 at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)   
 at navigate.main(navigate.java:55)(55 is output.write)

Comment: I dnt see why you are only attempting to write a single line to each file as you iterate through the list of files...

Comment: I am recording a list of all the files in a directory into a single text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `i < files.length` as condition in your for loop, but then access `copy[i]`. You might want to use something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(copy[i]);
    output.write(copy[i]);
}
```

Or even better, use a foreach loop:

```
for(final String element : copy) {
    System.out.println(element);
    output.write(element);
}
```

Comment: I now get the runtime exception                               Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
 at navigate.main(navigate.java:55) (55 is output.write)

Comment: Do you get another exception before that (from the first try/catch block)? Just remove all try/catch blocks and add `throws Exception` to your method signature.

Comment: I remembered I had a reason for it to be files.length (being that copy was bigger than the number of values in it). I fixed that issue and even with it still being copy.length it has gone back to the way it was before. if I comment out output.write then there is no difference that I can see.

Comment: Just post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Your code does not compile, so no-one can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Figured it out elsewhere, I truly thank you all for your help though.

Answer (score 2):

Do you ever close the writer?

In general, whenever you create an I/O resource (such as a reader/writer/database connection/etc), you should use a [finally block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) to ensure it's closed, something like this:

```
Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(...);
try {
    // do something with the writer; may be many lines of code
}
finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

(Note: Java 7 has more concise syntax for this pattern, [the try-with-resources block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).)

This is important for resource management (for example, if you don't close connections/files then eventually your process will run out of file handles and will not be able to open any more).

However, there's a more relevant issue too.  Many writers are buffered, to avoid the performance hit of writing one character at a time to the underlying operating system.  When you call `write` on them, they store that data in a buffer, and only actually write it to the file periodically (when it's "big enough" to be worth it) - this is called *flushing*.

If the writer is simply discarded before it has flushed the data, the file won't be updated.

You can call `flush()` manually, but it's rarely needed - calling `close()` on the writer will not only release all its resources, but will flush the buffers as well.  So with the `try / finally` pattern laid out above, it's *guaranteed* that whatever you write within the `try` block will be written to the file when your process terminates.  With your current code, there are no guarantees and it depends on the implementation of the writer.